# I want to copy a file to another server, but I'm getting a "could not find part of path" error

Tags: c#

I am making a simple windows forms application that essentially needs to copy a local file to a location on the server. I get a could.not.find.part.of.path error with I try:

```
file.CopyTo("\\123.45.678\\etcetc");
```

What tool do I need to use to fulfill my task?

Comment: Invalid IP, first backslash needs to be doubled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting an @ sign before the string:

```
file.CopyTo(@"\\123.45.678\etcetc");
```

You need two backslashes before the IP address, and that IP address looks wrong (it only has 3 octets, not four).

Comment: Alternatively, and less readable is of course file.CopyTo("\\\\123.45.678\\etcetc");

Answer (score 1):

try to change it to this:

```
file.CopyTo(@"\\123.45.678\etcetc");
```

Since you actually want 2 slashes, you need to make it a string literal, otherwise the double slash thinks you are escaping a single slash and results in you trying to find the path:

```
\123.45.678\etcetc
```

which doesn't exist.  Without a sting literal you could escape each slash and write it like this:

```
file.CopyTo("\\\\123.45.678\\etcetc");
```

but using a string literal is usually the better method.

Answer (score 0):

`file.CopyTo(@"\\123.45.678\etcetc");`

`@` allows you to use `\` without escaping

`\\` for addressing another computer

`\` for navigating within the computer